# ASP.NET RedirectToAction with parameters not getting passed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do a RedirectToAction with parameters like so:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "CPLCReservation", new { data = cp_sales_app_lc });
```

I am trying to pass the data to the CPLCReservation Controller's Index Method.

When I put a break point at the RedirectToAction, I can see cp_sales_app_lc is populated, when I goto the Index method of CPLCReservation Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(CP_Sales_App_LC data)
        {
            return View(data);
        }
```

data is null. Am I passing the data wrong?

cp_sales_app_lc is class variable of CP_Sales_App_LC and its defined like so:

```
CP_Sales_App_LC cp_sales_app_lc = new CP_Sales_App_LC();
```

I hope all this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` is handled via an HTTP status code (302 usually).  These redirects, as of HTTP 1.1, are always done via the HTTP verb `GET`.

Passing your *object* to the url parameter `data` will not call any serialization code.  (`GET` only deals with the URL, thus only strings).  You would have to serialize your object to use it with `RedirectToAction`.

Another option is to call the action method directly:

```
// Assuming both actions are in the CLPCReservationController class
public ActionResult SomeOtherEndpoint() {
    // return RedirectToAction("Index", "CPLCReservation", new { data = cp_sales_app_lc });
    return Index(cp_sales_all_lc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can catch parameter as string: `

```
public ActionResult Index(string data)
{
    return View(data);
}
```

Or you can do following:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
   TempData["data"]= new CP_Sales_App_LC();
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "CPLCReservation");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
   CP_Sales_App_LC data = (CP_Sales_App_LC)TempData["data"];
   return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is simple var type, like string or int, you can call:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "CPLCReservation", new { data = cp_sales_app_lc });
```

But if your var is complex, like a class with many items, you can use use the

```
ViewBag.data = cp_sales_app_lc
return RedirectToAction("Index", "CPLCReservation");
```

and then on CPLCReservation controller you recall the viewmodel

```
CP_Sales_App_LC data = (CP_Sales_App_LC)ViewModel.data;
return View(data);
```

to transport the complex model, like @Vadym Klyachyn said.

Also you can direct call the action like

```
return Index(cp_sales_all_lc);
```

but take in mind that if you have more code after it, it will return and execute that code. It wont leave the controller that call it.

I think the best way if you don't need a new controller is to use only a new View with the same controller with that model:

```
return View("newViewToDisplaydata", cp_sales_all_lc)
```